# xlCanTransmit() function does not work properly

Tags: c++, jna

I am trying to send CAN Frames with xlCanTransmit method. The problem is that it returns 0 (XL_SUCCESS), but the frame is empty. there are only zeroes in the Frame.

```java
IVxlApi.s_xl_event eventMsg = new IVxlApi.s_xl_event();

...
...

xlStatus = dll.xlCanTransmit(GlobalConfig.g_xlPortHandle, GlobalConfig.g_xlChannelMask[channelIndex],
                pEventCount, eventMsg.getPointer());
```

After Calling the function xlCanTransmit() the frame is sent, but there is no data in it.  The function is called from dll file and you can't debug it.

**My mapped Structure**

```java
 public static class s_xl_event extends Structure {

        public byte tag;
        public byte chanIndex;
        public byte[] transId = new byte[SHORT];
        public byte[] portHandle = new byte[SHORT];
        public byte flags;
        public byte reserved;
        public byte[] timeStamp = new byte[LONG];
        public s_xl_tag_data tagData;

        @Override
        public void read() {
            // read from native memory, populate tag
            super.read();
            // set union type based on tag
            switch (tag) {
                case XL_RECEIVE_MSG:
                case XL_TRANSMIT_MSG:
                    tagData.setType(s_xl_can_msg.class);
                    break;
                case XL_CHIP_STATE:
                    tagData.setType(s_xl_chip_state.class);
                    break;
                case XL_LIN_MSG:
                    tagData.setType(s_xl_lin_msg_api.class);
                    break;
                case XL_SYNC_PULSE:
                    tagData.setType(s_xl_sync_pulse.class);
                    break;
                case XL_RECEIVE_DAIO_DATA:
                    tagData.setType(s_xl_daio_data.class);
                    break;
                case XL_TRANSCEIVER:
                    tagData.setType(s_xl_transceiver.class);
                    break;
                case XL_RECEIVE_DAIO_PIGGY:
                    tagData.setType(s_xl_daio_piggy_data.class);
                    break;
                case XL_KLINE_MSG:
                    tagData.setType(s_xl_kline_data.class);
                    break;
                default:
                    // add default type or throw exception etc. 
                    tagData.setType(s_xl_can_msg.class);
                    break;
            }
            // now read tagData from native memory
            tagData.read();
        }

        @Override
        protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
            return Arrays.asList("tag", "chanIndex", "transId", "portHandle", "flags", "reserved", "timeStamp", "tagData");
        }
    }
```

CAN Frame in CANoe Trace

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQOO3.png)

The function on the native side looks like this

```cpp
DECL_STDXL_FUNC(xlCanTransmit, XLCANTRANSMIT, (
        XLportHandle  portHandle,
        XLaccess      accessMask,
        unsigned int* pEventCount,
        void* pEvents)
    );
```

My mapping in java

```java
short xlCanTransmit(long portHandle, long accessMask, IntByReference pEventCount, Pointer pEvents);
```

I wrote some random data manually and called the xlCanTransmit() function.

But in CANoe trace I see only empty frame with no data and id.

My send function in java

```java
 public short send(String txID, String dlc, String[] data, int channelIndex) {
        short xlStatus = IVxlApi.XL_ERROR;

        IntByReference pEventCount = new IntByReference(1);
        IVxlApi.s_xl_event eventMsg = new IVxlApi.s_xl_event();

        eventMsg.tag = IVxlApi.XL_TRANSMIT_MSG;

        eventMsg.tagData.msg.id[0] = 2;// = Long.parseLong(txID);

        eventMsg.tagData.msg.dlc[0] = 8;// = Short.parseShort(dlc);
        eventMsg.tagData.msg.flags[0] = 0;

        eventMsg.tagData.msg.data[0] = Byte.parseByte(data[0]);
        eventMsg.tagData.msg.data[1] = Byte.parseByte(data[1]);
        eventMsg.tagData.msg.data[2] = Byte.parseByte(data[2]);
        eventMsg.tagData.msg.data[3] = Byte.parseByte(data[3]);
        eventMsg.tagData.msg.data[4] = Byte.parseByte(data[4]);
        eventMsg.tagData.msg.data[5] = Byte.parseByte(data[5]);
        eventMsg.tagData.msg.data[6] = Byte.parseByte(data[6]);
        eventMsg.tagData.msg.data[7] = Byte.parseByte(data[7]);

        /*if(true){
            eventMsg.tagData.msg.id  |= IVxlApi.XL_CAN_EXT_MSG_ID;
        }*/
        eventMsg.write();
        xlStatus = dll.xlCanTransmit(GlobalConfig.g_xlPortHandle, GlobalConfig.g_xlChannelMask[channelIndex],
                pEventCount, eventMsg.getPointer());

         eventMsg.read();


        return xlStatus;
    }
```

CAN Frame in CANoe Trace

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQOO3.png)

After calling tagData.read() (line 475) the data initialized with zeroes
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGu03.png)

Answer (score 0):

The return value of `0` indicates the function preformed properly on the native side, but you haven't copied the native memory back to Java.

This is normally done automatically when you pass a `Structure` in a function, but you have passed the `Pointer` to the structure instead. Your last argument is `eventMsg.getPointer()`.  JNA doesn't know how the `Pointer` maps to your structure until you tell it to do so, and in the current way you're calling it requires using `read()` to copy the value back to JNA.

You could probably get the results you want by just executing `eventMsg.read()` after calling the function, but the better solition is to pass the `Structure` to the function in the first place and let JNA do the conversion to Pointer and auto-`read()` for you.  Change your function call to pass `eventMsg` as the argument.

Comment: after calling the read() method , my structure is empty. eventMsg contains some data before passing to the xlCanTransmit method. So I can't explain, why I can't see the data in CANoe Trace :( 

I have to map **void*** pointer  in java.

Comment: What does the API indicate should be returned in that data after you send?   I can't see any other issues with your code for sending, but not sure how you're detecting the sent message.

Comment: Daniel there are no need in particular moment to return what the API indicates. You can detect sent messages with CANoe. Only what I need is to send the data. I have tried without pointer, but I had same result. There was only empty frame :) May be I should re-check the structures and unions.

Comment: I think the problem is **read();** method. After calling it there are only zeroes in the structure. I called it manually before writing in the structure , but only ID is sent. DLC is 0 again. I can't explain this behavior